# ASP.NET MVC @Html.Checkbox() issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My checkbox still check after inserting data into database even if I don't have an ajax script in my insert operation.

But it is unchecked in my first adding attempt, I want to uncheck that when I add another data again

My Model:

```
public bool allowance { get; set; } = false;
```

My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PayrollSettingsAccount2/502", "Payroll", new { a = "3", b = "12", c = "44" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form_payrollaccount" }))
{ 
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.allowance, new { @id = "customCheck1", @class = "custom-control-input"})
}
```

Comment: `I want to uncheck that when I add another data again`-as you are not using ajax then whenever you submitting form it should refresh the form again. May be you are doing some wrong in any where in your code.

Comment: thank you for your care Sir @TanvirArjel but it's ok now..the problem of this is i'm not clearing the model after submitting the form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a checked the checkbox `allowance` and do a form post, then it will stay checked because of the ModelState. I you want the state to be like it was before the form post, use `ModelState.Clear();`

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Action(MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    //do stuff

    //removes all the data from the modelstate
    ModelState.Clear();

    return View(model);
}
```

More info: https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/modelstate-clear-is-required-to-display-back-your-model-object

Comment: Yes ! This can be the case. May be returning the same view after posting.

Comment: yes i used modelstate.clear() and case solve..again thank you Sir @TanvirArjel.